# Suddenly, I notice Windows 7 window manager behaves strangely

Tags: windows-7, firefox, dwm

Windows 7 window manager has recently started to behave strangely.

Firefox and Steam are running simultaneously. I am looking at the window of Firefox.

[image: Steam]

Now, I click on the Steam icon in the taskbar, the icon starts to blink in blue, and nothing has changed, I am still looking at the window of Firefox.

[image]

However, if I press alt-tab, I am able to bring the Steam window to the foreground.

The situation is then the same if I want to bring again the Firefox window to the forground.

Comment: Have you killed Explorer and tried to restart it? Does this happen with any app, even after rebooting, or only with a specific set of apps?

Comment: Nice catch. Problem solved after resetting Windows 7 theme.